# Jenkins pipeline Post-section doesn't recognize Agent properly

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following snippet of my Jenkins Pipeline script:

```
pipeline{
    
    agent none
    stages {  
    stage('First Stage'){
        agent { label 'AnotherAgent'}
        
        steps {
            ... Doing stuff
        }
    }
    ...More steps...
}

post {
    always{
        agent { label 'AnotherAgent'}
        xunit(tools: [ xUnitDotNet(pattern: 'path/to/logs*.xml') ])
    }
}
```

But when using this, I get the following error: `hudson.AbortException: Attempted to execute a step that requires a node context while ‘agent none’ was specified. Be sure to specify your own ‘node { ... }’ blocks when using ‘agent none’.`

Ok... I'll add the node there like this:

```
always{
    agent { node { label 'AnotherAgent'} }
    xunit(tools: [ xUnitDotNet(pattern: 'path/to/logs*.xml') ])
}
```

And now I get this error:

```
 WorkflowScript: 48: Missing required parameter: "label" @ line 48, column 17.
       agent { node { label 'AnotherAgent'} }
```

So how can I define an agent in the post-section of the Jenkins Pipeline script? First part before the Post works just fine, but the issue arises in the Post-section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to specify `agent any` not `none` at the top-level of pipeline if you didn't specify agent any in some stage. If so this will be failed and return the error you saw below;
`hudson.AbortException: Attempted to execute a step that requires a node context while ‘agent none’ was specified. Be sure to specify your own ‘node { ... }’ blocks when using ‘agent none’.`

Then in the post stage, you can define the node name with `node()`.
So here's the full Jenkinsfile you can run

```
pipeline{
    
    agent any
    stages {  
    stage('First Stage'){
        agent { label 'AnotherAgent'}
        
        steps {
            ... Doing stuff
        }
    }
    ...More steps...
}

post {
    always{
        node('AnotherAgent') { // let's stay your node name is "AnotherAgent"
           // run your command
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This solved the issue! Can you also expand, how can I add customWorkspace parameter into this Post-section? I need to fetch the test files in the Post-section from different workspace.

Comment: Ok, figured it out! I can just use: ```dir('new/path/here')( xunit stuff goes here)```

Comment: Sounds awesome and enjoy building on Jenkins!!

Answer (score 0):

`agent` is declarative syntax, `post` sections don't allow it. Syntactically it can be fixed by using a `node` step instead, but it's not a good solution:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('foo') {
            agent { label 'AnotherAgent'}
            steps {
            ...
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    post {
        always {
            node(label 'AnotherAgent') {
                xunit(...)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your `label` is an expression - you might get different agents in `stage/agent` and in `node`. It's a much better idea to add a post stage to your stage instead of the whole pipeline, then the stage agent would apply and you don't need to use `node`.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('foo') {
            agent { label 'AnotherAgent'}
            steps {
            ...
            }
            post {
                always {
                  xunit(...)
                }
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```